# Cypress - calling a function with parameters

Tags: javascript, function, automation, cypress

I want to create a function in cypress in which I can call as appropriate the environment on which to login and username. For example I want to append cy.login (live, username1)

I don't know exactly how to write to be correct in the code

```
 Cypress.Commands.add('Login', (env,username) => {
        env(staging) = cy.visit('https://staginglink') 
        env(live) = cy.visit('https://livelink') 
        username(username1) = {
            cy.get('input[name="Parameter.UserName"]').type('username1')
            cy.get('input[name="Parameter.Password"]').type('password1')
        }
            cy.contains('Login').click()
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

So your custom command will be like:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('Login', (env, username) => {
  cy.visit(env)
  cy.get('input[name="Parameter.UserName"]').type(username)
  cy.get('input[name="Parameter.Password"]').type('password1')
  cy.contains('Login').click()
})
```

Then in your test you can just write:

```js
cy.Login('https://staginglink','someusername1')
cy.Login('https://livelink','someusername2')
```

Comment: I want to simplify it even more and declare the link and username and password for each username declared in the test

Comment: So instead of two parameters `env, username` you want three parameters `env, username, password` ?

Comment: I want the username parameter to be declared inside the password function, and when I call cy.login (live, alex) for example, the function can also call the password for the alex username